# C# Sql Connection driver

Tags: c#, sql-server

What driver does a SQL Connection object connect to a SQL Server in order to run queries?

If I have the following code:

```
SQLConnection cn = new SqlConnection("server=ServerName;initial catalog=CorporateNA;Integrated Security=SSPI")
cn.Open();
```

Is the SQL Connection object using the ODBC driver SQL Server? I can't help but feel this is a stupid question, but Google searches for the topic are coming up fruitless. We are experiencing intermittent timeout issues on applications running on a server when they connect to the SQL Server and the DBA's are asking what driver it uses to connect. I do not know how to answer them.

Comment: You are using [ADO.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx(v=vs.110).aspx). You can [force ADO.NET to use ODBC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719762(v=vs.71).aspx), if you want to though. But you shouldn't unless you have a great reason to do so.

Comment: You should tell your DBAs you are using the .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server.  Telling them you are using ADO.NET won't be enough, since, as @Icemanind points out, you could use an ODBC driver with ADO.NET (or even an OleDB driver).

Comment: Did you increase the timeout? SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 500;  SQL Server are known to get fragmented which slows down the dattabase.  Try compacting the Database to see if problem gets resolved.

Comment: Yes jdweng, we have increased the timeout. DBA's are saying they aren't even seeing any timeout event on the server so we are looking at issues between the client and the server. Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`, your driver is the [.NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cd7c08.aspx) (commonly known as ***SqlClient***) unless you specified otherwise